# Kentia Palm turning crispy and yellow and dry

Tags: palm, kentia

I have a Kentia Palm and read that they don’t like that much water. Try to water only once a week during winter but some leaves turning brown and then yellow and then dry a whole branch so i had to cut them off. I have a moisture meter and no matter how much water i put into it, the soil is always dry, even right after I water it. I’m so confused! Not sure if i overwater or underwater it. I live in Vegas so the weather is kind of dry in here but I saw there’re many of Kentia Palm are thriving in restaurants in hotels in here so i’m very confused. I very much like the Kentia Palm but it seems so hard to take care especially with a big one in a big heavy pot, can’t really check up on the root. Please help me! Thank you.[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there an A/C vent nearby? Lots of plants cannot tolerate being near an A/C vent. Or a heat vent in colder parts of the world.